# как исправить ошибку при попытки залить миграцию laravel?

Tags: laravel

в общем поля все валидные работает если все перевести на c $table->string на $table->text

но данные то все поместятся в string почему он на text если перевести работает, и если часть полей закомментирую не важно каких то тоже заливается миграция

название
примерно все одинаковой длины 117 полей все string

```
$table->string('program_native')->nullable()->comment('Количество реализуемых программ обучения русскому языку как родному');
```

//ошибка

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

на форуме https://wiki.iphoster.net/wiki/MySQL_-_ERROR_1118_-_Row_size_too_large._The_maximum_row_size_for_the_used_table_type,_not_counting_BLOBs
нашел
Ошибка означает, что при создании таблицы общий размер всех полей больше чем 65535 и нужно заменить varchar(n) тип данных на text

так а что теперь нельзя иметь все поля строкого типа? если мне нужно хранить именно эти данные в string

спасибо

Comment: А текст не строка? ;)

Comment: ну оно же больше места занимает зачем для телефона выделять Максимальная длина 65535 символов (64 Кб) ?

Comment: нет, это максимальная длина полей в таблице в mysql, а не их значений. varchar(255) в одной колонке использует 255 * 4 + 1 байтов. Откуда у вас 117 полей в таблице???? как такое вообще возможно? вы слышали что-то о нормализации бд? у меня максимум за мою практику было 12 в одной таблице полей